# Ask a question on conditional independence?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$ be a nonsingular matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^p$.In the textbook, it says

$Y\perp\kern-5pt\perp X \mid \beta^T A^{-1}    [(AX+b)-b]   \Rightarrow  Y\perp\kern-5pt\perp X \mid \beta^T A^{-1}    (AX+b)$

What is the property that can drop $-b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, you'd kind of expect that conditioning on $U$ and conditioning on some deterministic, one-to-one function of $U$ should give the same result -- conditioning involves "using the information in $U$", and if $f$ is one-to-one, then $f(U)$ has the "same information" as $U$, so conditioning on either $U$ and $f(U)$ ought to be the same.  (Technically, $f$ and its inverse also need to be measurable.)  Anyway, this particular example is just adding a deterministic constant $\beta^TA^{-1}b$ to the conditioning expression, a particularly simple measurable one-to-one function (that is measurable and has measurable inverse).

More generally, if $f$ is a measurable, one-to-one function with measurable inverse and $U$ is a random variable, then conditioning on $U$ and conditioning on $f(U)$ are equivalent: the conditional expectations $E[X|U]$ and $E[X|f(U)]$ are the same for all $X$; the conditional distribution of $X$ given $U$ is the same as that given $f(U)$, and the conditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ given $U$ is equivalent to the conditional independence of $X$ and $Y$ given $f(U)$.

Proving this is "easy" but requires some measure theory -- you need to show that $\sigma(U)=\sigma(f(U))$.

[For any measurable $B$, we have $(f\circ U)^{-1}(B) = U^{-1}(f^{-1}(B))$, and the measurability of $f$ implies $f^{-1}(B)$ is measurable.  This gives $\sigma(f(U))\subseteq\sigma(U)$.  Conversely, for any measurable $C$, $B := f(C)$ is measurable by measurability of $f^{-1}$, and $f$ one-to-one ensures that $U^{-1}(C) = U^{-1}(f^{-1}(B)) = (f\circ U)^{-1}(B)$.  This gives $\sigma(U)\subseteq\sigma(f(U))$.]